# php, MySQL, fpdf and $_Get?

Tags: php, mysql, get

I have a search form, in which the user inputs a last name.

This is then compared to a MySQL table and outputs (on a new php page) a list of search results.

Then, of those results, I want to be able to click a specific one, which then outputs to a pdf, using fpdf.

First page or Form page code...

```
<select name="metode" size="1">
<option value="lname">Last Name</option>
<option value="id">ID</option>
</select> <input type="text" name="search" size="25">  <br>
Search database: <input type="submit" value="Go!!" name="Go"></p>

//query details table begins
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM paid WHERE $metode LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT 0, 50");
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<a href="pdfout.php">' . $info['address'] . '</a>';
    echo " <br>";
    echo $info['fname'];
    echo "&nbsp";
    echo $info['lname'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

On the `pdfout.php` page, how do I recall the selected record (from the previous page) that the user clicked?

I have tried various $_GET statements but can't seem to get that to work. Or do I need to be using sessions?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to pass the parameter via GET to pdfout.php.  When you are echoing out the the database query results, you should add a record identifier to the `href` for the link like this:

```
echo '<a href="pdfout.php?id=' . $info['your_id_field'] . '">' . $info['address'] . '</a>';
```

Then you can use `$_GET['id']` in `pdfout.php` to get the id for the record you are interested in.

As another note,you really should look to use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql` as it is deprecated.  Also you need to make sure you have properly escaped `$metode` and `$search` against SQL injection (it is unclear here whether that has been done, so I figured I would mention it).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed the form tag and method type. so try this in your html..

```
<form  action="page.php" method="get">
  <select name="metode" size="1">
  <option value="lname">Last Name</option>
  <option value="id">ID</option>
  </select> <input type="text" name="search" size="25">  <br>
  Search database: <input type="submit" value="Go!!" name="Go"></p>
</form>
```

and in the page.php get this

```
$search=$_GET['search'];
```